# Adding VisualChild to Canvas does not work - not displayed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, addition

I have to write a class that inherits from Canvas and that is able to add Visuals to the canvasbase.

So I wrote this code:

```
class TestCanvas : Canvas
{
    VisualCollection visuals;

    public TestCanvas()
    {
        visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = 200,
            Height = 200,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 5,
            Fill = Brushes.Black
        };
        visuals.Add(rect);
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return visuals.Count;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > visuals.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

        return visuals[index];
    }
}
```

But if I click on it and I add this Rectangle it is not displayed. 
So does anyone has an idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to programatically add children to a derived Canvas, you can simply do it like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle   
{   
    Width = 200,   
    Height = 200,   
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,   
    StrokeThickness = 5,   
    Fill = Brushes.Black   
};   

Canvas.SetLeft(rect, ...);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, ...);

Children.Add(rect);
```

No need to go down to the Visual layer and override `VisualChildrenCount` and `GetVisualChild`.

If for any other reason you have to use Visuals, then there is no need to use a Canvas. You might derive from `UIElement` or `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: hmmm ok if i have any more questions i will ask again ... ill try it thx

Comment: hmmm the problem is i need to down to the visual layer. And I need the canvas. My english is not as good as to explain you that quite good. But I am planing to create some kind of a drawing tool. It is based on this idea: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools

Here is also used a Canvas baseclass as container and a visualcollection. And i think this is a quite pretty way.

Comment: Haven't looked into the project you're referring to. But you are mixing concepts here. You should definitely either manage [ContainerVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.aspx) children **or** [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) (e.g. Canvas) children, not both.

Comment: ok i have solution.
just create a DrawingVisual and draw on it manually by using a drawingcontext. see this for more information: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7751